# HTTP basic authentication-POST request

Tags: http, post, parse-platform, http-headers

Using `Parse` server , i have to send `http post request`  from some hardware device. So i have to construct a request ,with authentication .

This one, is working great on any browser and returns a JSON file :

```
 https://y4eI4XmKNT5D6MVtC565xkEjBAkggTlTMt1erNKv:javascript-key=NOkyJ0XBB4gdANXSCGE0slnH0QKXhZ5OPf7ma4Gk@api.parse.com/1/classes/DATA/TXcgRDCCRR
```

Than if i send it with this GET request :

```
GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n 
HOST: https://y4eI4XmKNT5D6MVtC565xkEjBAkggTlTMt1erNKv:javascript-key=NOkyJ0XBB4gdANXSCGE0slnH0QKXhZ5OPf7ma4Gk@api.parse.com/1/classes/DATA/TXcgRDCCRR\r\n\r\n
```

I get error. I was told that i have to construct a request with authentication, from this simple line that i showed here .

Question is, how does it looks, the `GET` request and the authentication ?

This is their API docs:
https://parse.com/docs/rest

Thanks .

Comment: Whats the error you got? I could get the result in url auth or header auth.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you have is 2 things combined.

2 servers, a proxy step that takes the JSON-File response for HTTP-Call#1 to a non-parse-api host  and redirects as a proxy would that JSON response in a 2nd POST call on the Parse API??

If thats what you want to do and you are using NodeJS as your proxy stack then you could decompose/recompose as follows:

get the value for the parse.com APPID

use the JS-Key that you have in conjunction with the appid key value as per any of the parse docs ( JS or REST ) for required header info in calls on parse. If using REST then you dont use the JS-key and need another key value for REST.

get the response body ( the JSON-file ) from call # 1 and include its bytes as the POST/PUT body in call #2.

If call #2 is really a GET and you have to send along the JSON-File's bytes then you have to encode it for use with a GET.

You need to analyse how the parse context ( DATA/TXcgRDCCRR ) affects what you are doing in step 2. That looks like a reference to ( $ParseClass/$ParseObjectId )

are you updated a specific parse object ID with the JSON from call 1?

are you POSTing a new object to DATA

not really clear from the question